# why my sed script to split FASTA file is slow?

Tags: sed, fasta, sequence-alignment

I have a 600 Mb FASTA file containing many alignments blocks from 12 species and I want to split them into smaller FASTA files containing one block each with its corresponding alignments

I have a sed script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
for i in {0..Nblocks}; do
  sed -n "/block_index=$i|/,/^$/p" genome12species.fasta > bloque$i.fasta
done
```

This works at a small scale but for a big file as 600Mb it takes too long, around 2 days. I don't think this is a matter of the computer I am running.

Does anyone knows how to make this faster?

The input Fasta file looks like this:

> dm3.chr3R(-):17092630-17092781|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=dm3|dm3_4_0
>   GGCGGAGATCAAGAATCGCGTCGGGCCGCCGTCCAGCGCCACTGACAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAACACCAAATCCGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattatacaatta
>   droGri2.scaffold_15074(-):2610183-2610334|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droGri2|droGri2_4_0
>   GGCGGAGATCAAGAATCGTGTTGGGCCGCCGTCGAGCGCCACCGATAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAGGGACGCCCAGTGGAAAACAATAGATCTGGTTGCTGCTAAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCATTATTTTATTATACAATTa
>   droMoj3.scaffold_6540(+):33866311-33866462|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droMoj3|droMoj3_4_0
>   TGCCGAGATTAAGAATCGTGTCGGTCCGCCGTCCAGCGCAACCGACAATGCAAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAGGGACGTCCAGTGGAGAACACCAGATCTGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCATTATTTTATTatacaatta
>   droVir3.scaffold_12822(+):1248119-1248270|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droVir3|droVir3_4_0
>   GGCCGAGATTAAGAATCGCGTCGGGCCGCCGTCCAGCGCCACCGATAATGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAGGGTCGTCCAGTGGAGAACACCAAATCTGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattatacaatta
>   droWil1.scaffold_181130(-):16071336-16071488|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droWil1|droWil1_4_0
>   GGCCGAGATTAAGAATCGTGTTGGGCCGCCGTCCAGCGCCACTGATAATGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAATACCAAATCCGGTTGCTGCTGAATAAACTCTGATTGTGAATCATTATTTTATTATACAATTA
>   droPer1.super_19(-):1310088-1310239|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droPer1|droPer1_4_0
>   GGCTGAGATCAAGAATCGCGTCGGACCGCCGTCCAGCGCCACCGACAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAAACCCAATTCTGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattatacaatta
>   dp4.chr2(-):5593491-5593642|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=dp4|dp4_4_0
>   GGCTGAGATCAAGAATCGCGTCGGACCGCCGTCCAGCGCCACCGACAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAAGCCCAATTCTGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattatacaatta
>   droAna3.scaffold_13340(-):3754154-3754305|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droAna3|droAna3_4_0
>   GGCCGAGATCAAGAATCGCGTCGGGCCACCGTCCAGCGCCACCGACAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAACACCAGATCCGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattataaaatta
>   droEre2.scaffold_4770(+):4567591-4567742|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droEre2|droEre2_4_0
>   GGCCGAGATCAAGAATCGCGTCGGGCCGCCGTCCAGCGCCACCGACAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAACACCAAATCCGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattatacaatta
>   droYak2.chr3R(-):5883047-5883198|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droYak2|droYak2_4_0
>   GGCCGAGATCAAGAATCGCGTCGGGCCGCCATCCAGCGCCACCGACAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAACACCAAATCCGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattatacaatta
>   droSec1.super_38(+):36432-36583|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droSec1|droSec1_4_0
>   GGCGGAGATCAAGAATCGCGTCGGTCCGCCGTCCAGCGCCACTGACAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAACACCAAATCCGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattatacaatta
>   droSim1.chr3R(+):4366350-4366501|sequence_index=0|block_index=4|species=droSim1|droSim1_4_0
>   GGCGGAGATCAAGAATCGCGTCGGGCCGCCGTCCAGCGCCACTGACAACGCTAGCAAAGTGAAAATCGATCAAGGACGTCCAGTGGAAAACACCAAATCCGGTTGCTGCTGAATAA-CTCTGATTGTGAATCattattttattatacaatta
>
> dm3.chr3R(-):17092781-17092867|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=dm3|dm3_5_0
>   GAGTACGCCGCCCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACTTCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACCAACGTTGAGCAGGCCTTCATGACGATGGC
>   droSim1.chr3R(+):4366264-4366350|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droSim1|droSim1_5_0
>   GAGTACGCCGCCCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACTTCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACCAACGTTGAGCAGGCCTTTATGACGATGGC
>   droSec1.super_38(+):36346-36432|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droSec1|droSec1_5_0
>   GAGTACGCCGCCCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACTTCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACCAACGTTGAGCAGGCCTTCATGACGATGGC
>   droYak2.chr3R(-):5883198-5883284|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droYak2|droYak2_5_0
>   GAGTACGCCGCCCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACATCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACCAACGTGGAGCAGGCCTTCATGACGATGGC
>   droEre2.scaffold_4770(+):4567505-4567591|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droEre2|droEre2_5_0
>   GAGTACGCCGCCCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACTTCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACCAACGTGGAGCAGGCCTTCATGACGATGGC
>   droAna3.scaffold_13340(+):20375068-20375148|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droAna3|droAna3_5_0
>   ------GCCGAAAACTTCGACATGCCCTTCTTCGAGGTCTCTTGCAAGTCAAACATCAATATTGAAGATGCGTTTCTTTCCCTGGC
>   dp4.chr2(-):5593642-5593728|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=dp4|dp4_5_0
>   GAGTATGCAGCTCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTTCTTGAAACTTCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACGAACGTGGAGCAGGCCTTCATGACGATGGC
>   droPer1.super_19(-):1310239-1310325|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droPer1|droPer1_5_0
>   GAGTATGCAGCTCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTTCTTGAAACTTCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACGAACGTGGAGCAGGCCTTCATGACGATGGC
>   droWil1.scaffold_181130(-):16071488-16071574|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droWil1|droWil1_5_0
>   GAATATGCGGCTCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACTTCGGCAAAGAGTGCCACCAATGTGGAGCAGGCCTTTATGACGATGGC
>   droVir3.scaffold_12822(+):1248033-1248119|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droVir3|droVir3_5_0
>   GAGTACGCACATCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACTTCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACCAACGTGGAGCAGGCATTTATGACGATGGC
>   droMoj3.scaffold_6540(+):33866225-33866311|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droMoj3|droMoj3_5_0
>   GAGTATGCACATCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACTTCGGCCAAGAGCGCCACCAATGTAGAGCAGGCATTCATGACGATGGC
>   droGri2.scaffold_15074(-):2610334-2610420|sequence_index=0|block_index=5|species=droGri2|droGri2_5_0
>   GAGTACGCAAATCAGTTAGGCATTCCATTCCTTGAAACTTCGGCGAAGAGTGCCACCAATGTGGAACAGGCATTCATGACGATGGC

Comment: definitely `awk` will be able to solve this for your with 1 pass thru the file and should  only take minutes. If you are "married" to sed, then changing to `.../^$/{p,q}'` may help speed things up, but still nowhere near as fast as awk. Add a small set of fake/sample data that illustrates your file format (5-10 lines max, 30-60 chars wide max) and people will dive in on this. (I have to go out ;-/ ) . Good luck.

Comment: Does `{0..Nblocks}` actually work? (I don't think it does.)

Comment: Also, You should read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour, http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   Good luck.

Comment: @shellter. Thanks for the insight. I'm not married to sed, I'm just such a noob on informatics that sed was my only idea. I didn't know awk existed till today.

Comment: @BenjaminW. It does not, I have to manually type the number of blocks.

Comment: please, please, is a line 153 chars wide really necessary to help solve your problem? What about the data `GAGTACGCAAATC....` is needed to solve your problem. This makes help with your problem something that people can't cut/paste into a terminal without extra work. Also, please use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an awk oneliner to get you started - it uses the same regex range as your sed - the matched block_index is in m[1] - 600MB should take just a few minutes

```
awk 'match($0, /block_index=([0-9]+)\|/, m),/^$/ {print >"bloque"m[1]".fasta"}'
```

Comment: Would you mind posting timings for this solution? Thanks

Comment: Of Course! Ididn't timed it precisely but it ran a file of 650Mb and 215000 blocks of 12 species alignments each in about 20min.

Comment: that's reasonable - do I understand right that 215,000 blocks mean 215,000 files were created?